# Mechanism of this addition-elimination process

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, elimination

In Part 1 of the synthesis of [Maoecrystal V](https://synarchive.com/syn/295) (found on synarchive), the last step subjects a $\ce {\alpha, \beta}$-unsaturated ketone to $\ce {I2}$ and pyridine, as shown below:

[image]

I am wondering what is the mechanism that takes place for the elimination process. It is unlikely to be an E2 process since that requires anti stereochemistry for the $\ce {H}$ and $\ce {I}$ that are being eliminated. After anti-addition of the $\ce {I2}$ molecule to the double bond, the $\ce {H}$ and $\ce {I}$ atoms would both be syn to each other. Since this is a ketone with acidic $\ce {\alpha}$ hydrogens, a E1cB mechanism is likely operating and thus, we observe the elimination of the $\ce {\alpha}$ hydrogen and the iodine atom on the $\ce {\beta}$ position. Is my hypothesis correct?

Comment: This is a reasonable hypothesis. It could also be proceeding by a Baylis-Hillman type halogenation via the pyridinium enolate.

Comment: Yeah, it's rather pyridine being eliminated.

Comment: @Mithoron Well... E1cB or Baylis-Hillman, both are just equally likely hypotheses